# Merge/Add an object into an array - Javscript

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an two arrays of objects. My goal is to replace an object from the second array into the first one based upon 'id'. I have a working solution, but would like to extend it by adding the object to the first array if a value isnt found. Please advice.

```js
function mergeById(arr) {
  return {
    with: function(arr2) {
      return _.map(arr, item => {
        return _.find(arr2, obj => obj.id === item.id) || item
      })
    }
  }
}

var result = mergeById([{
      id: '124',
      name: 'qqq'
    },
    {
      id: '589',
      name: 'www'
    },
    {
      id: '567',
      name: 'rrr'
    }
  ])
  .with([{
    id: '124',
    name: 'ttt'
  }, {
    id: '45',
    name: 'yyy'
  }])

console.log(result);

/**
[
  {
    "id": "124",
    "name": "ttt"
  },
  {
    "id": "589",
    "name": "www"
  },
  {
    "id": "567",
    "name": "rrr"
  },
  {
    id: '45',
    name: 'yyy'
  }
]
**/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter the second array and add the values who have no common id.

```js
function mergeById(arr) {
    return {
        with: function(arr2) {
            return [
                ..._.map(arr, item => _.find(arr2, obj => obj.id === item.id) || item),
                ..._.filter(arr2, item => !_.some(arr, obj => obj.id === item.id))
            ];
        }
    }
}

var result = mergeById([{ id: '124', name: 'qqq' }, { id: '589', name: 'www' }, { id: '567', name: 'rrr' } ])
      .with([{ id: '124', name: 'ttt' }, { id: '45', name: 'yyy' }]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

A shorter approach with a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and single loops for every array.

```js
function mergeById(array) {
    const
        add2map = (m, o) => m.set(o.id, o),
        map = array.reduce(add2map, new Map);
    return {
        with: function(array2) {
            return Array.from(array2
                .reduce(add2map, map)
                .values()
            );
        }
    }
}

var result = mergeById([{ id: '124', name: 'qqq' }, { id: '589', name: 'www' }, { id: '567', name: 'rrr' } ])
      .with([{ id: '124', name: 'ttt' }, { id: '45', name: 'yyy' }]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you as always :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `_.differenceBy(arr2, arr, 'id')` to find all items that appear in `arr2` that doesn't have a counterpart in `arr` by `id`, and concat them to the results of the `_.map()` action.

Note: instead using `_.find()` (O(n)) on each iteration, iterate `arr2` once with `_.keyBy()` (O(n)) to create a dictionary `{ [id]: item }`, and then get the items in O(1).

```js
const mergeById = arr => ({
  with(arr2) {
    const arr2Dict = _.keyBy(arr2, 'id')

    return _.map(arr, item => arr2Dict[item.id] || item)
      .concat(_.differenceBy(arr2, arr, 'id'))
  }
})

const result = mergeById([{ id: '124', name: 'qqq' }, { id: '589', name: 'www' }, { id: '567', name: 'rrr' } ])
      .with([{ id: '124', name: 'ttt' }, { id: '45', name: 'yyy' }])

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

You can replace/add in a single loop by concating both arrays, reducing to a Map, and just adding the items by `id` to the Map:

```js
const mergeById = arr => ({
  with(arr2) {
    return Array.from(
      [...arr, ...arr2]
        .reduce((r, o) => r.set(o.id, o), new Map)
        .values()
    )
  }
})

const result = mergeById([{ id: '124', name: 'qqq' }, { id: '589', name: 'www' }, { id: '567', name: 'rrr' } ])
      .with([{ id: '124', name: 'ttt' }, { id: '45', name: 'yyy' }])

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why the two  ? ?

Comment: be more specific

Comment: Sorry, there were two question marks in your code. Looks like you edited it now. Thanks

Comment: The 2 question marks `??` are called [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator), but there are not necessary for this answer, and I thought that they might be confusing that's why I edited them out.